# how to get balance for multiple addresses(batch request)?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I need to check the balance for multiple addresses (i.e. 100) a [eth_getbalance seems](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) to accept only one address.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, retrieving balances for multiple addresses is not supported yet by the RPC standard.

However, what I've came up with so far is this: I pack all balance calls into promises and do `Promise.all` by chunks of `50` requests for instance. It waits for the first `50` balances, then queries next `50` and so on. Code:

```
async function getAllAddressBalances (addresses, batch = 50) {
    const map = new Map();
    let processed = 0;
    process.stdout.write(`Processed: ${ processed }/${ addresses.length }`);
    for (const batch of splitArray(addresses, batch)) {
        let retry = true,
            pss = processed;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                await Promise.all(batch.map(address => (async function () {
                    let balance = 0;
                    balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
                    process.stdout.write(`\rProcessed: ${ ++processed }/${ addresses.length }`);
                    if (balance === 0)
                        return;
                    map.set(address, balance);
                })()));
            } catch (e) { // Sometimes rate limit may apply, this tries over and over again
                console.log(`Exceptions caught (possibly node rate limit), retrying in 5 seconds...`);
                retry = true;
                await delay(5);
                processed = pss;
                continue;
            }
            retry = false;
        }
    }
    process.stdout.write(`\n`);
    return map;
};

function splitArray (array, len) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += len) {
        arr.push(array.slice(i, Math.min(i + len, array.length)));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Alternatively, you can rely on third-party APIs like Etherscan, there are a plenty of those. As for Etherscan, they have an endpoint that enables you to [get Ether Balance for multiple Addresses in a single call](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts).

Answer (score 1):

You might write and deploy a smart contract that has a single method that will check the balance of multiple accounts and return you multiple balances concatenated. Then call this method and decode result.

Here the solution for a similar problem:
https://github.com/pooltogether/etherplex

A problem that **etherplex** solves is similar but not exactly the same:
You have a single address but multiple tokens, special smart contract + JS wrapper that uses `ether.js` returns you `unpacked` response from this dedicated balance checker contract

Answer (score -3):

geth is using jsonrpc which is an open specification.